# How Vue.js 1x filterBy works?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'd like to implement a filter in my app like the filterBY Vue.js provided in filters on 1x versions...

I'm trying to make a Computed Property to return an array with the objects that match with some string passed in a variable... But my aim is make something reusable and not give the attributes that searched every time...

Thanks for your attention guys

Comment: I can't tell if you already know this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Replacing-the-filterBy-Filter  

Maybe show some Vue 1 code for what you're trying to do?

Comment: Hi, well i'm trying to filter an array of object but deeply in all object attributes and children's, but we find a solution that solve this problem... I'll make a fiddle to show the result, thanks for you attention!! =D

Answer (score 0):

i had a help on facebook group **Vue.js Brazil** by the user **Israel Sant'Anna** that solved absolutely this demand, look the workaround:

```
var filterList = function(arr, filterTerm){
if (filterTerm === '') return arr
return deepFilter(arr, filterTerm)
```

}

var deepFilter = function(arr, filterTerm){
    return arr.filter(item => {

```
if (typeof item === 'object'){
        return deepFilter(Object.values(item), filterTerm).length > 0;
}

if(item.toString().indexOf(filterTerm)>=0){
    return true;
}
```

})
}

https://jsfiddle.net/igortrindade/3jr27cwm/6/